# Publishing an app to Play Store and beta testing

Tags: google-play, publishing, beta-testing

I read about alpha/beta testing of apps in Play Developer Console. I have almost understood the concept of beta/alpha testing. Just have a question:

I want my app to be visible in Play Store but only those people can download it who are invited (like using email addresses or G+ communities). Seems like Alpha/Beta Testing hides the app from public.

But I have seen several apps (Can't think of the name) in Play Store with the text similar to **This app is still in beta. Please wait until we reach more audience.** And as expected there's no install button.

I want something similar to this. Public can see but only those can install who join G+ community.

**Does open/closed beta testing provide such feature?**

Comment: So apparently no one knows answer to this simple question :(

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to come across this post and though it's a rather old post, hope you found the answer, if not, then, yes, you can do what you ask for.

In the Google Play store, once you upload a build, you have an option on the left side menu that allows you to send the build for testing to certain users.

I tend to use "Closed testing" as it gives me more control.

If you've never set this up, once you select this option, there will be a few things for you to select, such as testers, where you can set a group of tester you want to have test your app, then push it for testing.

You will have to provide your testers with the opt-in link, which is available when you're setting up the testing track and it looks something like this:

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/

Once your app is approved, your testers can use the link above, log in with the email address they gave you to be part of testing and become testers.

After they do that, there will be a link to download the app from the Playstore.

Hope this helps.